# windows 2016 firewall

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-2016

Привет! Недавно поручили мне админить win2016, но так уж сложилось, что я unix-админ и понятия не имею как там и чего. Собсно поставил IIS, развернул чего требовалось, и теперь надо это и "удалённый раб. стол" (3389) как-то закрыть для всего мира и оставить открытым только для некоторых адресов. Как это сделать?

Пытался найти разрешающие правила в `firewall.cpl -> Advanced settings` , но там нет ничего что разрешало бы трафик до 80 и 443 либо для IIS. `netsh advfirewall firewall dump` из под админа - возвращает пустоту, при этом все профили (domain, public, private) активны и их правила я вижу в `firewall.cpl` .

Comment: А есть возможность между инетрнетом и виндой поставить хоть что-нибудь unix-like, cisco-dlink-etc-like? Скока читал и смотрел - никто не советует выставлять винду в интернет в качестве шлюза.

Comment: @donRumata это не шлюз, это вируталка с виндой. Хостер никак их не закрывает, увы :(

Comment: Есть ipfw for windows, но он чё-то заглох. А хостер точно не предоставляет никаких услуг по фаерволлам?